# How do I achieve MECE (Mutually Exclusive, Collectively Exhaustive) in SQL?

Tags: sql, relational-database, rdbms

I'm looking to create a series of table relationships that together will be mutually exclusive, collectively exhaustive, i.e. form a partition of a given set. For example, imagine you had the following relationship:

An animal is either (only) a cat or dog.

A dog has a name and a favorite toy. A cat has a name and a favorite food.

A first stab at trying to model this kind of relationship in SQL would be an `animals` table with an `animalId` column and then a `dogs` table with a `dogId` and a `favoriteToy` column where the `dogId` has a foreign key reference to an `animalId`. Then you could have a `cats` table with a `catId` and a `favoriteFood` column where the `catId` has a foreign key reference to an `animalId`.

However, this has a couple of problems, some that seem solvable, some not.

- I can add a `dogId` and a `catId` referencing the same `animalId` (I think this is NOT a fundamental problem since I can add an additional column in animals that is a two member enum which is replicated by cat and dog and used to form a composite foreign key)
- I can add an `animalId` in `animals` that has neither a `catId` or `dogId`.

On the other hand I could denormalize everything into a single `animals` table with `favoriteFood` and `favoriteToy` columns, but this seems to lack the constraint that one and only one of those columns must be non-null.

In short it seems I can ensure mutual exclusivity, but cannot ensure collective exhaustivity or I can ensure collective exhaustivity, but cannot ensure mutual exclusivity. Is there another approach that gives me both? It looks like you might need some sort of circular dependence here, but I'm not sure if there's a good way of doing that without involving unnecessary `null`s (which seems like a case of the cure being worse than the disease).

Comment: Yes introducing nulls is worse than the disease: well done for understanding that. What you need is an 'inter-relational constraint' to the `dogtoy` and `catfood` auxiliary relations. Beware that although these are part of the SQL standard, many vendors haven't implemented anything more than Foreign Keys. So you might be forced to write database triggers to validate updates. That's a disease arguably worse than nulls.

Comment: @AntC what do you mean by "inter-relational constraint"? Are you aware of any vendors who have implemented what you're talking about?

Comment: @AntC are you talking about something like `CHECK` that's in e.g. Postgres or Sqlite?

Comment: "inter-relational constraint" means a constraint _between_ two different relations/tables. A Foreign Key constraint is an example, but not strong enough for this case. Contrast an "intra-relational constraint" is _within_ a single relation/table, such as a Key. Yes you declare constraints with `CHECK` (that's SQL standard), but many vendors place restrictions on how complex can be the expression to check for.